# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher. Can't find the path to 'location'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I was building APK for a flutter project and encountered this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

My android/build.gradle file is

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
        //noinspection DifferentKotlinGradleVersion
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I can't find where I need to change the kotlin-gradle-plugin version. Please help.

I tried changing the ext.kotlin_version but seems like it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

try to upgrade your flutter version using this command.

- `flutter upgrade`

*Edit:*

#### Gradle Upgrade

- From `android` folder open `gradle-wrapper.properties`

[image]

- You need to replace `distributionUrl` with this

> https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

[image]

- Run `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`
- Run the android app then

Comment: Tried it. Seems like it didn't help. It's throwing the same error.

Comment: @hudaifa77 try to upgrade `gradle.properties`

Comment: Can you please guide me to upgrade it? I'm quite new to this.

Comment: @hudaifa77 Try the edited steps.